# Arrest [development]

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

[development](/questions/tagged/development) seems rather poorly defined; most of its questions are about generally developing things (which is not a topic Meta is for) and the rest are about developing SE (which is arguably what most of Meta is for, so not useful as a tag).

Should we shut it down? (With only 16 questions, this is not difficult to do.)

Comment: Maybe some can be retagged to more specific tags like [tag:architecture].

Comment: Seriously, you passed on the opportunity to title your question "Arrest [development]"?

Comment: @DanBron: I didn't think of it.

Comment: Agree with @rene, we can do it ourselves by retagging - only 15 questions should be easy enough.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, sure, I'm just double-checking to make sure I didn't miss something.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII: Well, I upvoted most of the answers to the first one a while ago. Does that count?

Comment: The tag seems to have more specific guidance now to be about development of Stack Exchange, and the remaining questions are on that topic. Does it still need burnination?

Comment: @ale: That just means one part of burnination has been completed (closing off-topic questions). The absurd over-generality of the tag hasn't been addressed at all.